# ClassLoader fails after migration to Play Framework 2.3

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I am in the process of migrating from Play Framework 2.2 to 2.3.8 and I've gotten through some of the errors, but keep finding more. The new one doesn't provide much hints though. I get this error:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoClassDefFoundError: play/api/mvc/SimpleResult]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:170) ~[play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128) ~[play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/api/mvc/SimpleResult
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571) ~[spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:490) ~[spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.api.mvc.SimpleResult
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
```

I have removed all references to `SimpleResult` with the proper `Result` as described in the migration guide. I figure there is something in one of my plugins that may be referencing it. I am using these plugins:

```
javaCore,
javaJdbc,
javaEbean,
filters,
cache, 
javaWs,
"org.drools" % "drools-core" % "5.5.0.Final",
"org.drools" % "drools-compiler" % "5.5.0.Final",
"org.jbpm" % "jbpm-bpmn2" % "5.4.0.Final",
"org.jbpm" % "jbpm-flow" % "5.4.0.Final",

"org.drools" % "drools-persistence-jpa" % "5.5.0.Final",
"org.jbpm" % "jbpm-persistence-jpa" % "5.4.0.Final",
"org.jbpm" % "jbpm-workitems" % "5.4.0.Final",
"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "4.3.0.Final",
"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.0.Final",
"org.springframework" % "spring-orm" % "4.1.1.RELEASE",
"org.springframework" % "spring-expression" % "4.1.1.RELEASE",
"org.springframework" % "spring-aop" % "4.1.1.RELEASE",
"org.springframework" % "spring-web" % "4.1.1.RELEASE",
"org.drools" % "drools-spring" % "5.5.0.Final",

"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.2.1",  //can we use 4.0.1
"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.2",      //can we use 4.0.1
"com.github.detro.ghostdriver" % "phantomjsdriver" % "1.0.4" % "test",

"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "2.4.0",
"org.apache.ws.xmlschema" % "xmlschema-core" % "2.1.0",
"org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "4.1.1.RELEASE",
"org.apache.cxf" % "cxf-api" % "2.7.10",
"org.apache.cxf" % "cxf-rt-core" % "2.7.10",
"org.apache.cxf" % "cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws" % "2.7.10",

"com.mohiva" % "play-html-compressor_2.10" % "0.3.1"
```

I don't know if it's my plugins though, that was just a guess. If it is, is there a way to figure out which one is referencing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `clean`?

Comment: Hello again m-z. I thought I did, but i'll give it another shot just because.

Comment: The fact that it's looking for `SimpleResult` someone still leads me to believe some sort of artifact of it is left somewhere (like in already compiled code).

Comment: Same thing happens after a clean... It does look like it's holding onto something but i did a clean check out on a different computer and same thing. There is definitely still something in there that references SimpleResult... just don't know what.

Comment: Weirdly, if i search for SimpleResult, nothing but some log files show up (with the errors described) except SublimeText says that the binary code for an external library com.h2database.h2-1.3.170.jar DOES contain the text. Not even sure if this is a real lead or not. Why would that library reference play's API anyways? Running out of ideas clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered some libraries that I had dependencies on that were failing because they depended on Play 2.2. Always be careful about which JARs you let into your lib folder! Changing those dependencies to updated versions retrieved through managed sources fixed the issue AND removed unnecessary JARs